# Need Help on 3 Table Relations Ms access and Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert, database-relations

I created 3 Tables in ms access in which the Table Person is the only one that contains a Primary key `TABLE PERSON(ID,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME)` , and i connect it to 2 `TABLES AMOUNT(ID,amount,Term )`, `TABLE TIME(ID,start,due)`.

[image: Table relations]

The time table and id table has no PK and ID formats are Numbers.

When I try to add Data in my Database using Vb.Net it shows this error `You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'P'.`

Here is the whole code:

```
 Public Function insert_person(ByVal fname As String, ByVal mname As String, ByVal lname As String)
        Dim connect As OleDbConnection = con()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = connect.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into P(fname,mname,lname)values(fname,mname,lname)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lname
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connect.Close()
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function insert_amount(ByVal empid As Integer, ByVal amount As Double, ByVal term As Integer)
        Dim connect As OleDbConnection = con()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = connect.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into A(empid,amount,term) values(@empid,@amount,@term)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = empid
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount", OleDbType.Double).Value = amount
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@term", OleDbType.Integer).Value = term
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connect.Close()
        Return 0
    End Function
```

When i check my DB to see if The records had been saved the only record saved is `TABLE P` `TABLE amount` `TABLE time` do not add anything

Comment: Why is the strict compiler option set to `Off` and why do you store everything as `String` aka. `varchar` in the database?

Comment: You don't add a value for the ID field in the P table. This means that this ID is an Autonumber and it is generated automatically from Access every time you add a record. To get back that value and use it in the other insert queries (where is mandatory that you know the ID of the person in relationship with your amount and time data) you should execute another command just before closing the connection in the first query. SELECT @@IDENTITY

Comment: 1. Your relationship screen does not match your code - where is A.empid? -- 2. Again, you need to post the code that **calls** your `insert_*` functions.

Comment: Found The answer Thanks Guys now for my last question im currently building my Login Form i can login using a DataGridView. What im Trying to Achieve is that when i got the correct user account and been transferred to another Form i want those attributes to be converted into Text something like a mini profile. w/o selecting anything from the DGV

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a syntax error in `insert_amount`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter(CType("[empid]"
```

2. `time` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe#__toc272229040) in Access, you should name this table differently.
3. **Every** table should have a primary key. You'll get all sorts of problems without.
4. The error message you get means that you have a relationship with **Referential Integrity** between `P` and the other tables. You need to pass and insert an `empid` that exists in `P`.

Comment: how can i pass the empid to the others Table then?all i do is Dim i as Integer pass the i as parameter for the insert_time function how can i pass the PK of the P to other Tables?

Comment: @IvanMiguelAntonioLorenzo: see Steve's comment. You should post the code that calls your `insert_*` functions to get more help.

Comment: added a Relation of my access mind taking a look at it and what im trying to aim is to execute them all together